# How to find a key value from a key value match?

Tags: python, dictionary, ordereddictionary

I have a really long ordered dict that looks similar to this:

```
OrderedDict([('JIRAUSER16100', {'name': 'john.smith', 'fullname': 'John Smith', 'email': 'John.Smith@domain.test', 'active': True}), ('JIRAUSER16300', {'name': 'susan.jones', 'fullname': 'Susan Jones', 'email': 'Susan.Jones@domain.test', 'active': True})])
```

How can I search through this list to find a key value based on a key value match? For example, for Susan Jones, I'd like to find her email based on the name value? Is there a pythonic way to find that without just looping through the entire dictionary?

Currently I'm just doing this below, but it seems inefficient when I have to go through the list a thousand times. I'm curious if there is a "find" method of some sort?

```
searchname = "susan.jones"
for user in my_ordered_dict.items():
   if user[1]["name"] == searchname:
      print(user[1]["email"])
```

Comment: No, there's nothing built-in that does this. You could create another dictionarythat uses names as keys. But whenever you modify a name in the main dict you'll also have to update the name-based dict.

Answer (score 1):

Two ways you could potentially improve on this.  You say your `OrderedDict` is really long, so I'd recommend the first option, since quickly become faster than the second as the size of your data grows.

1) **use [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/)**:

```
In [1]: from collections import OrderedDict

In [2]: import pandas as pd

In [3]: d = OrderedDict([
   ...:     ('JIRAUSER16100', {'name': 'john.smith',
   ...:                        'fullname': 'John Smith',
   ...:                        'email': 'John.Smith@domain.test',
   ...:                        'active': True}),
   ...:     ('JIRAUSER16300', {'name': 'susan.jones',
   ...:                        'fullname': 'Susan Jones',
   ...:                        'email': 'Susan.Jones@domain.test',
   ...:                        'active': True})
   ...: ])
In [4]: df = pd.DataFrame(d).T

In [5]: df
Out[5]:
                      name     fullname                    email active
JIRAUSER16100   john.smith   John Smith   John.Smith@domain.test   True
JIRAUSER16300  susan.jones  Susan Jones  Susan.Jones@domain.test   True

In [6]: df.loc[df['name'] == 'susan.jones', 'email'][0]
Out[6]: 'Susan.Jones@domain.test'
```

On the scale of easy-to-learn-but-weak to hard-to-learn-but-powerful, `pandas` is fairly far toward the latter extreme.  There's a decent amount to unpack here if you aren't familiar with `pandas`, so for the sake of brevity I won't go into it. But feel free to comment with any questions if more explanation would help.

2) **Use the built-in [`next`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) function**

This will allow you to avoid looping through the full dictionary.  To make a long story really short, you can pass `next` a generator with a ternary expression, and it will essentially run through an iterable until it finds the *first* item that satisfies the given condition.  So in your case,

```
In [7]: next(entry['email'] for entry in d.values() if entry['name'] == 'susan.jones')
Out[7]: 'Susan.Jones@domain.test'
```

would work.  It will save you time verses looping through the entire dict, but unlike option 1, its speed will depend on where in your `OrderedDict` the entry you're trying to find is located.  Unless you for some reason need to stick exclusively to the standard library, Pandas will be much faster on any reasonably sized dataset.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Brilliant, thank you! I really like your second option with the "next" function. I always like using built-in features whenever possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a specific match you will have to iterate through your structure until you find it so you don't have to go through the entire dictionary.

Something like:

```
In [19]: d = OrderedDict([('JIRAUSER16100', {'name': 'john.smith', 'fullname': 'John Smith', 'email': 'John.Smith@domain.test', 
    ...: 'active': True}), ('JIRAUSER16300', {'name': 'susan.jones', 'fullname': 'Susan Jones', 'email': 'Susan.Jones@domain.tes
    ...: t', 'active': True})]) 
    ...:                                                                                                                        

In [20]: def find_entry_by_subkey(sub_key, sub_key_value, data): 
    ...:     for entry in data.values(): 
    ...:         if entry[sub_key] == sub_key_value: 
    ...:             return entry 
    ...:                                                                                                                        

In [21]: find_entry_by_subkey('email', 'Susan.Jones@domain.test', d)                                                            
Out[21]: 
{'name': 'susan.jones',
 'fullname': 'Susan Jones',
 'email': 'Susan.Jones@domain.test',
 'active': True
```